# HTML5 context.clip() using image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to use an image as a clipping mask instead of creating a shape like this:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
// Clip a rectangular area
ctx.rect(50,20,200,120);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.clip();
```

I have tried to `context.drawImage('myimg.png')` on top of the context and clip but that did not work.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit?  AFAIK you can only clip to a path, but there might be some other way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I have created an image mask using a template. I am wanting to use the custom shape in the mask image to clip the full image.

Comment: Would you care to update your question showing how the suggestions in my answer lead to a solution?  I know the approach is probably correct, but I'd also be interested in seeing an actual implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only directly `clip` using a path.

If you have an image that you wish to clip by, you can *probably* achieve this by drawing your content in *another* canvas, and then using `globalCompositeOperation` combined with `drawImage` (with the mask) to remove the bits you don't want.

You would then then use `.drawImage` again (possibly with a different `globalCompositeOperation`) to merge that clipped image with your original content.

See for example http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-global-composite-operations-tutorial/